# Role of coefficient in Multinomial NB

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multinomial, countvectorizer

My MultinomialNB classifier was instantiated and trained on vectorized fake/real news articles, and now I'm trying to understand the meaning behind the coefficients.

```
nb_classifier = MultinomialNB()

# Extracting the class labels: ('Fake' or 'Real')
class_labels = nb_classifier.classes_

# Extract the features_names from the vectorizer I used
feature_names = count_vectorizer.get_feature_names()

# Zip the feature_names together with the coefficient array and sort by weights
feat_with_weights = sorted(zip(nb_classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))

print(class_labels[0], feat_with_weights[-20:]) #Or, class_labels[1] = 'Real'
```

Results in:

> FAKE [(-6.2632792078858461, 'sanders'), (-6.2426599206831099,
>   'house'), (-6.1832365002123097, 'senate'), (-6.1641883052416144,
>   'time'), (-6.1091285280585872, 'iraq'), (-5.9297875994027711,
>   'republicans'),...]

I understand that the higher coefficient (-5.9) means that the token has a higher predictiveness than the -6.2. **But I'm not sure where the relationship is. Does it mean that the token 'republicans' is highly associated with Fake news or Real news.**